# Changing ionic float input color

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to change the color for my ion-input and ion-label (from default black to white). I`m doing something like this:

```
    <ion-item style="color:#ffffff">
      <ion-label floating style="color:#ffffff">Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" type="password" #password="ngModel" required >
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

Tha label color changes,but the bottom line of the input dosen't. Looking at the ionic docs, I didn't found something specific for this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by overriding Ionic's style rules like this:

```
/* Workaround to hide android default validation colors */
ion-item.item-md.item-input.input-has-focus .item-inner,
ion-item.item-md.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner,
ion-item.item-md.item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner {
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/* Workaround to hide window phone default validation colors */
ion-item.item-wp.item-input.input-has-focus .text-input,
ion-item.item-wp.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .text-input,
ion-item.item-wp.item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus) .text-input {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Where are you including these style rules? Please verify that the styles are being loaded properly. I've checked and the answer should work: [working gif](https://gyazo.com/b3d5c6cc33f35f08c2e9d1a5fdbede22)

Comment: I`m adding those lines to app.scss

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following.

```
ion-item { --border-color: var(--ion-color-danger, #f1453d);}
```